# Which parts to draw in an infinite world?

Tags: procedural-generation, culling, frustum

I have an infinite world (from Perlin Noise).

[image]

The world is generated in sectors that are that are big cubes (each with a random colour, in the image above; my sectors are 10x10x10).

I'm currently putting the sectors in a hash-table tagged by their top-left-front corner coordinate.  I can loop through all the sectors I've already generated and see if they intersect the frustum.

But how can I compute instead the sectors that I haven't generated but are visible and need generating on-demand?

Even if I have an octree or some other spatial index, I need to compute the sectors that are visible inside the frustum rather than those I've already generated.

Answer (score 1):

just generate and keep all blocks within a X radius of the player in the hash table, and then frustum filter for drawing, same way minecraft does it

it's cheaper to keep more sectors in memory and then filter than keep just enough and generate

Comment: The benefit to ratchet's approach is that you can find the sweet spot between the number of sectors you've generated and not yet visible and those visible so that as the player moves, you can spread the generation of new sectors across several frames and have their generation complete before they ever need to be made visible.